# Implement a GitLab Runner that builds in one VM and deploys in another VM

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How can I configure GitLab CI runners to perform the build stage in one VM and then deploy to another VM, considering that each runner is located in different data centers?

I have a requirement to set up my GitLab CI/CD pipeline with runners in different data centers. I want to ensure that the build stage is executed in one VM, and then the deployment is performed in another VM located in a separate data center.

I would appreciate guidance on how to configure this setup using GitLab CI. Specifically, I need to know how to define the runners and their respective configurations to achieve the desired build and deployment separation. Additionally, any best practices or considerations for managing the distributed runners and ensuring efficient communication between the VMs would be helpful.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

After conducting some research, I have identified a specific requirement and devised a solution. Now, I am seeking guidance and assistance to implement this solution. I would appreciate guidance on whether this approach is feasible and, if so, any instructions or recommendations to successfully implement it.

Comment: do you mean in a pipeline with for example two jobs, you want the build job to happen on one runner, and then the deploy job to happen in a different runner? If thats the case you can add tags to your runners and use tags in each job to select the appropriate runner https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags

Comment: @ChrisDoyle  i want  the runner does the "stages: - build-image" for my .Next apps in Vm#1 and then deploy it in Vm#2.

Comment: what is your devised solution? if you can post it, i can comment on it. Also, there is no need for any communication between VMs, just VMs to gitlab server.